# Instantiate case class with values to be set for its members

Tags: scala, case-class

Consider this case class

```
case class sample(val s: String = { /*compiled code*/ })
{
  val name:String = { /*compiled code*/ }
  val no:Int = { /*compiled code*/ }
}
```

I need to create instance of this class with particular values set to name and no. 
But I cannot use another class which extends this class. I have to pass the same class instance.

Answer (score 2):

You mean someone has gone to the trouble of making sure `name` and `no` are set a particular way and cannot be changed, and you want to make them contain something else, which may violate all sorts of assumptions?  That's not a good idea, and the JVM will stop you from doing something so foolish (barring absurdly difficult tricks involving custom classloaders for everything).

If you merely mean that *you* want to set those vals, but not usually have to worry about them in the constructor, then there are a variety of solutions.  One is to use lazy vals and private vars with setters:

```
case class C(val s: String = "fish") {
  private var myN: Option[Int] = None
  def initializeN(n0: Int) {
    myN = Some(n0)
    if (n != n0) throw new Exception("Already initialized")
  }
  lazy val n: Int = myN.getOrElse(s.length)   // s.length is your code block
}
```

Which works like so:

```
scala> C("salmon")
res0: C = C(salmon)

scala> res0.initializeN(2); res0.n
res1: Int = 2

scala> C("herring")
res1: C = C(herring)

scala> res1.n
res2: Int = 5

scala> res1.initializeN(2)
java.lang.Exception: Already initialized
    at C.initializeN(<console>:11)
        ...
```

There are various other tricks you can play if you want compile-time safety of initialization.  Later parameter blocks can refer to earlier ones, and don't appear as match arguments:

```
case class D(val s: String = "fish")(val n: Int = s.length) {}
```

You can overload constructors:

```
case class E(val s: String, n: Int) {
  def this(s: String) = this(s, s.length)
  def this() = this("fish")
}
```

and various mixtures of the above are possible also.

Comment: I want to send back the instance of this class with modified values.

Comment: @user2140033 - You may not.  The values are immutable.  You can't change them.  I cannot begin to express how horribly it would break things if it was trivial to change values that are indicated as never changing.

Answer (score 1):

And making `name` and `no` constructor parameter is not an option?

```
case class Sample(s: String = { /*compiled code*/ },
                  name: String = { /*compiled code*/ },
                  no: Int = { /*compiled code*/ })
```

I assume that the `/* compiled code */` determines the default values of the fields. You can use the code as follows:

```
Sample()                   // all default values
Sample("some value for s") // default values for name and no
Sample("s", "name", 123)   // explicit values, no defaults
```

Comment: I think no, because it looks like a third party code decompiled from jar with IntelliJ IDEA